# homebrew does not work with Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: xcode, xcode8, homebrew, macos-high-sierra

I'm getting:

```
Error: Your Xcode (8.3.3) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 9.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

If I'm running high-sierra is it not possible to install packages using brew with Xcode 8.3.3?

Comment: The answer to your question lies in the error message: No it doesn’t work with Xcode 8.3.3. You have to either delete it (most formulae can still be installed without Xcode) or upgrade it.

Comment: Please confirm on High Sierra Can I use Xcode 8.3.3?